# Write to console screen without Console.SetCursorPosition(?,?)

Tags: c#, console

Is there a way to write a string in specific coordinates in a console window without using Console.SetCursorPosition(?,?)

Comment: Why not use `SetCursorPosition`?

Comment: Yes, use the native Win32 function `SetConsoleCursorPosition` directly (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,1269), but why?

Comment: It's for an assignment, assignment says do not use it. Thank you, I'm not sure if we allowed to use the native function either

Comment: You could have a string variable, and use it as the "buffer". You set the values on it, and write the string directly to the console (note that you have to clear it every time.)

Comment: I think you're having an X/Y problem here. If you're using the Win32 function (which is normally used in `Console.SetCursorPosition`), it's just cheating. What's the exact problem assignment? If you need to write a string in some line at some position, you can also uses spaces and newline as fillers?

Comment: Probably a more detailed description of what you're trying to do would help.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < row - 1; i++) { Console.WriteLine(); } Console.Write(new string(' ', col - 1)); Console.Write(text);`

Comment: The assignment is making a small game where you have a character in a console window at a certain position in the consoles limits(width height), if you press right it goes right and down it goes down, but we are not allowed to use 'Console.SetCursorPosition)' as one of our rules to draw the object in those specific coordinates

Comment: Redraw your game frame fully on every change of in game-objects, then. Try to write a function that will compute your frame buffer as a multi-line `string` with empty lines / spaces for fillers, then `Console.Clear()`, then `Console.Write(framebuf)`, as per suggestions above.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt I will try this and see what happens, i have been out of coding for a year so still rusty, will try to figure it out

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt isn't there a way to write like at a certain location, using coordinates

Comment: You could clear the consoles and write it fully from scratch. Basically what a GPU does every Frame. But genereally game development should not be done in Console. A core of modern game development is the "game loop" and anything but dedicated Game Developmetn approachs is rarely able to handle that level of drawing.

Comment: @Christopher it's not really a game, just merely a small assignment to make a single letter character move when a key is pressed without using  `Console.SetCursorPosition`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General idea of solving this problem:

- Compute the current "frame" of your game, which is just lines of text, completely
- Clear the console
- Print the entire "frame" to the console
- Wait for input, modify in-game objects, repeat.

E.g., I wrote the following "console game": The player is a "*", the rest is filled with "-". Window adapts to resizes automatically. Player can move in every direction with arrow keys (left,right,up,down). No error checking done.

It's a basic setup that uses an array of `StringBuilder` objects to be able to do easy string modification (`strings` are immutable). Would make sense to write a general `DrawTextInFramebuffer(string text, int x, int y, framebuffer)` though.

**Edit**: Also, mandatory video suggestion: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkMZI5Jbf18, Retro-Racing game using the console window and colored blocks in C++, though C# implementation would also be possible.

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace StackOverflowTesting
{
    class Program
    {
        /* Player position */
        static int PlayerX = 1;
        static int PlayerY = 1;

        static string ComputeFrameBuffer()
        {
            //What are the current dimensions of the console window
            int consoleWindowHeight = Console.WindowHeight;
            int consoleWindowWidth = Console.WindowWidth - 1;  //-1 prevents line overflow

            //Compute framebuffer line-wise
            var lines = new StringBuilder[consoleWindowHeight];

            for(int y = 0; y < consoleWindowHeight; y++)
            {
                //Create the line as a repetition of consoleWindowWidth spaces or other filler.
                lines[y] = new StringBuilder(string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat("-", consoleWindowWidth)));
                for (int x = 0; x < consoleWindowWidth; x++) 
                {
                    //What do we need to draw at this (x,y) position? is the player here? 
                    if(PlayerX == x && PlayerY == y)
                    {
                        //Yes. Use a '*' for the player "sprite"..
                        lines[y][x] = '*';
                    }
                }
            }
            //Concatinate all lines
            return string.Join("\n", lines.Select(l => l.ToString()));
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool runGame = true;
            while (runGame)
            {
                //Render current frame
                string frame = ComputeFrameBuffer();
                Console.Clear();
                Console.Write(frame);

                //Grab next user input
                var pressedKey = Console.ReadKey(false);
                //Handle stuff
                switch (pressedKey.Key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                        PlayerX--;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                        PlayerX++;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                        PlayerY--; //Coordinate system is upper left = (0,0). Downwards increases Y.
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                        PlayerY++;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.Escape:
                        runGame = false;
                        break;
                }
                //clamp coordinates to be always within bounds
                int maxY = Console.WindowHeight;
                int maxX = Console.WindowWidth - 1; 
                if (PlayerX < 0) PlayerX = 0;
                if (PlayerX >= maxX) PlayerX = maxX - 1;
                if (PlayerY < 0) PlayerY = 0;
                if(PlayerY >= maxY) PlayerY = maxY - 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm Trying to limit the drawing so that it only draws within the console. If it gets to the end of the console like the, for example, the right-hand side it will stay there unless the person presses the left key then it would go left, same for up down. I've tried various methods but it doesn't seem to work, this is my last attempt:

Comment: @Cleaven Code was modified.

Answer (score 0):

To control the drawing of the character to within the viewable console box, just replace the switch statement with this one:

```
switch (pressedKey.Key)
{
      case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
      {
           PlayerX--;
           if (PlayerX == -1)
               PlayerX++;
      } 
      break;
      case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
      {
           PlayerX++;
           if(PlayerX == width-1)
              PlayerX--;
      } 
      break;
      case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
      {
           PlayerY--;
           if (PlayerY == -1)
               PlayerY++;
      } 
      break;
      case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
      {
           PlayerY++;
           if (PlayerY == height)
               PlayerY--;
      } 
      break;
      case ConsoleKey.E:
           runGame = false;
           break;
}
```